# Not able to map a custom domain to a hosted app in azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-appservice

I'm trying to expose an API for my registred app when I add the API : I get this error message:

> Failed to update Application ID URI application property. Error detail: Values of IdentifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain: summarizxxxx.z28.web.core.windows.net

I suppose that the `core.windows.net` is protected so I should create my custom domain.

In azure storage networking tab when I add a custom domain I get this error

[image]

I have already the custom domain declared

[image]

What should I do to map the `hmz-digital.fr` domain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Custom Domains tab where you are trying to add your domain, there are instructions to configure CName record on your DNS. Have you followed the steps for direct or indirect validation?

Configure a custom domain for accessing blob data in your Azure storage account, like [www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com). There are two methods you can use to set up a custom domain.

1. Create a CNAME record with your DNS provider that points from your domain (like [www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com)) to satess.blob.core.windows.net or xxxxxxxxx.z13.web.core.windows.net then enter you domain below. This method is simpler, but results in a brief downtime while Azure verifies the domain registration.
2. Create a CNAME record with your DNS provider that points from the "asverify" subdomain (like asverify.www.contoso.com) to asverify.satess.blob.core.windows.net or asverify. xxxxxxxxx.z13.web.core.windows.net. After this step completes, enter your domain below (exclude the 'asverify' subdomain). This method does not incur any downtime. To use this method, select the 'Use indirect CNAME validation' checkbox.

The custom domain can not be added w/o doing this step.